# Cannot change locale in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

For some reason, it's not possible to change the locale in my app. I have created `config/locales/el.yml` and set the configuration in `application.rb` as follows:

```
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :el, :zh]
```

If I try to change the locale in the Rails console, it just doesn't change.

```
[1] pry(main)> I18n.locale = :el
:el
[2] pry(main)> I18n.locale
:en
```

Translations always default to English even when another locale is specified and the key exists in the translated file e.g.

```
[3] pry(main)> I18n.t("hello", :el)
"Hello world"
```

en.yml:

```
en:
  hello: Hello world
```

el.yml:

```
el:
  hello: Hello Greek world
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Don't use `I18n.locale =` to change locales. It is not thread safe and can leak into subsequent requests. Instead use `I18n.with_locale`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this solves my issue because even when I try to set the locale, it doesn't change from `:en`.

Comment: I think the only way really to get to the bottom with this is by creating a minimal example that reproduces the behavior. You're well on way but we need to know the rails version and the exact steps to reproduce it. I can't reproduce this on 6.0.1.

Comment: @max I found a solution (see below), but have incorporated your suggestion into my code in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm dealing with legacy code and there were a bunch of leftover gems that had gone stale so – like cleaning out the refrigerator – I tossed them from my `Gemfile` and now it works! The gems I discarded were:

- gettext_i18n_rails
- gettext
- i15r
- i18n-tasks
- i18n-js

To be honest, maybe I just don't know how to use them, but in any case I don't need them – so now they are gone.